# wordpress pagination not working in localhost server

Tags: wordpress

I have used wordpress below code for pagination in local-host template but dont know why it is not working. Its showing all pages number nicely but any page number i click its only display first page.

```
global $wp_query;  
$total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;  
if ($total_pages > 1){  
$current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));  
echo paginate_links(array(  
  'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',  
  'format' => '/page/%#%',  
  'current' => $current_page,  
  'total' => $total_pages,  
));  
}
```

my permalink settings is:

> localhost/my-blog/sample-post/

and query post:

> $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 2);

anybody please give me idea what to do next for working this pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with WP_Query. You may try it:

```
global $wp_query;
$big = 999999999; // Need an unlikely integer
echo paginate_links( array( 'base'    => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
                            'format'  => '?paged=%#%',
                            'current' => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
                            'total'   => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
                            'end_size'=> 1,
                            'mid_size'=> 10 ) );
```

In `Settings -> Readings`  set `Blog pages show at most` to the number of posts you want to display in each page and in `Settings -> Discussion` set the pagination behavior

Answer (score 1):

```
  <global $wp_query;
$total = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
// only bother with the rest if we have more than 1 page!
if ( $total > 1 )  {
     // get the current page
     if ( !$current_page = get_query_var('paged') )
          $current_page = 1;
     // structure of "format" depends on whether we're using pretty permalinks
     $format = empty( get_option('permalink_structure') ) ? '&page=%#%' : 'page/%#%/';
     echo paginate_links(array(
          'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
          'format' => $format,
          'current' => $current_page,
          'total' => $total,
          'mid_size' => 4,
          'type' => 'list'
     ));
}
```

Please set a argument as per requirement and also refer this link [My helps you](http://www.wprecipes.com/easy-wordpress-pagination-without-plugins)

And let me know if you face problem

Thanks and Regards

Comment: thanks for ur reply.. having same problem. Displaying first page although my url show >//localhost/my-blog/page/2

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem by reading the URL param using straight-up PHP, instead of get_query_var('paged'), simply use this:

```
$_GET['paged']
```